# How to get Navigate Edition of HERE maps?

Tags: sdk, here-api

So I am trying to get the navigation edition, but it says contact your HERE representative. Who exactly is HERE representative? 
I did mail them but in vain. No reply yet.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this question?

Comment: Thanks for contacting us. If possible please message us your primary location, and we can forward your concern to related regional team.

Comment: My primary location is Delhi, India.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not programming related; the question is about the release / availability of a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking with the product management team, the 4.x Navigate edition is still in the closed beta testing phase. It is planned to go commercial during second half of 2020. We do offer the Premium edition of the SDK. Please check if you can waiting till Q3 for the Navigate edition, and during the mean time please feel free to try the Premium edition. The Premium edition is included in our Freemium plan btw.